# How to create real-time charts using EON and PubNub Java API?

Tags: java, pubnub

I am creating an PoC which requires the below:

1. Publish message every 2 seconds using the Java API.
2. Subscribe the message and create a chart using EON

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub EON Charts

[The EON subscribe side is done for you with many examples](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/), you just need to provide you own keys.

And publish messages from your Java app every 2 seconds in the format that EON (really D3) is expecting. Again, examples on how to publish are provided in the examples.